# Bluetooth background scan in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.ios

I found the Objective-C examples

```
[manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
                                options:@{
    CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey:@[
        [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"7905F431-B5CE-4E99-A40F-4B1E122D00D0"]]}];
```

And try to convert Xamarin.iOS code

```
PeripheralScanningOptions option = new PeripheralScanningOptions(NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(CBCentralManager.ScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey, CBUUID.FromString("84C80001-4A61-60B9-3A2B-1300855E588C")));

CBCM.ScanForPeripherals(new []{ CBUUID.FromString("84C80001-4A61-60B9-3A2B-1300855E588C") }, option);
```

but is not working,

how to use CBCentralManager.ScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey in Xamarin.iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Your C# code does not look like the ObjC code.

```
[manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
```

means the first parameter is `null`, not an `CBUUID` array. This would be closer:

```
CBCM.ScanForPeripherals (null, option);
```

Also ObjC convention is to have object and keys (not keys and object) so the parameters you use with `FromObjectAndKey` should be reversed.

Comment: change the code to

CBCM.ScanForPeripherals((CBUUID[])null, NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(CBUUID.FromString("84C80001-4A61-60B9-3A2B-1300855E588C"), CBCentralManager.ScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey));

but is not working,
could not scan any device

Comment: I could not find on the Bluetooth background scanning examples code,
even Bluetooth examples code are too few  :(

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW54), you need to set background capability for using it in background from info.plist file. Enable background mode and select use Bluetooth LE accessory.

Here is a screenshot of info.plist file with setting for using BLE in background. 
 [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution below that you can try for you:

using Plugin.BLE (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.BLE/) I can get the service uuid of a beacon/device using advertisement records like so

foreach (AdvertisementRecord record in e.Device.AdvertisementRecords)

```
        {
            if (record.Type == AdvertisementRecordType.UuidsComplete128Bit || record.Type == AdvertisementRecordType.UuidsComplete16Bit)
            {
                b.ServiceUUID = record.Data;
                break;
            }
        }
```

I then pass in a list of CBUUID with the ServiceUUID values added to them:

```
 foreach (Beacon beacon in beaconList)
        {
            cbuuidList.Add(CBUUID.FromBytes(beacon.ServiceUUID));
        }

        CBUUID[] uuid = cbuuidList.ToArray();
        BLEManager.ScanForPeripherals(uuid);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must enable the background mode for Bluetooth LE accessories, like Benjamin said.

Secondly, you must call ScanForPeripherals with a UUID, of the main service that is exposed in the advertising packet of the peripheral.  This is a requirement for background BLE scanning, per Apple's docs. (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html)

An example of a UUID is: 00000011-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB, where 0011 at the end of the first segment is the short UUID of the service, and the rest is the BASE_UUID (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery).  This would scan for any peripherals advertising the Human Interface Device Profile (HID).

```
...
var serviceUuid = Guid.Parse("00000011-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
var serviceUuids = new CBUUID[] { CBUUID.FromString(serviceUuid.ToString()) };
central.ScanForPeripherals(serviceUuids, new PeripheralScanningOptions { AllowDuplicatesKey = true });
```

This part is optional:
new PeripheralScanningOptions { AllowDuplicatesKey = true }